# Is it possible to sync SKEmitterNodes with a Video using AVSynchronizedLayer?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avfoundation

I want to synchronize the movement of a `SKEmitterNode` with a video using `AVSynchronizedLayer`. So as the video seeks forward, seeks backward or just plays, the `SKEmitterNode` moves accordingly. I know this can be done easily with `CALayers`, but can it be done with `SKEmitterNode(s)`?

I tried to apply SKActions on the `SKEmitterNode` but those actions once applied, are not getting in sync with the player layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the SKEmitterNode as a child of a SKNode, and use the SKNode as a movement "anchor". Move the SKNode with actions, then the emitter(s) moves with it. This becomes much more elegant and gives you a power of nested rotation, too... if needs be.

But, probably more important, if you provide a SKSpriteNode to the anchor SKNode, you'll see exactly how/what movement is occurring.

One of the problems with particles systems: **the rate of emission influences how you perceive emitter movement.** They might be moving at the right rates, but the delays in emission and/or colouring/scaling of the particles may make it look like they're delayed or otherwise out of sync.

### UPDATE

If you're wondering how to use the output from your `SKKEyFrameSequence', there's three things to do.

1. Mention it in the original question as being what you're needing to get at and use for synching
2. Take advantage of the fact that it sets a sequence that is gettable:

[image]

3. Sample what it's doing, and apply whatever parts of those values you need to your... well, whatever...

[image]

Comment: How does it solve the problem of sync with video?

Applying `SKAction` to `SKNode` does not guarantee to sync with video frames, that said can be done only with KeyFrameAnimations. But `SKEmitterNode's` position property is not supported for `SKKeyFrameSequence`

Comment: Which do you want to synchronise with your video: movement of the emitter or properties of your particle emittance?

Comment: edited. Perhaps edit your question, too, so I can see what you're actually trying to do. @ShashankAgarwal